# There is no modversions.h

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel, driver

I am trying to compile linux driver I found on this [link](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue69/mathew.html).
I downloaded linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic into /usr/src folder.

I found modversions.h in linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic/include/config/ and it is empty.

My makefile looks like this:

```
INCLUDEDIR = /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic/include

CFLAGS = -c  -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -O -Wall -I$(INCLUDEDIR)



VER = $(shell awk -F\" '/REL/ {print $$2}' $(INCLUDEDIR)/linux/version.h)

OBJS = myaudio.o

all:    $(OBJS)

myaudio.o:
    cc $(CFLAGS) myaudio.c  

install:
    install -c myaudio.o 

clean:
    rm -f myaudio.o core
```

I have tried to pass -I /usr/src/linux-3.16.0-30-generic/include/config into make command.

Comment: Your driver is very old for 3.16 kernel. Building process for new kernels differs from old one. See, e.g., http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt

Comment: Thanks a lot . I have to modify my makefile than? I am new in kernel programming